# RTC poll scm in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, rtc

In Jenkins, for RTC download and accept option I am using commands, because RTC plugin is not working properly because of .project collision. 
While using RTC plugin, it tries to download code from repository workspace, which has components from different streams. RTC plugin download without option "-i" (which is used to create the dirs for the components), and it leads to .project file collision from components. So I had to give command for load with "-i" option.

Now I want to poll scm in jenkins. As there is no SCM configured for RTC, how can I configure Poll SCM in jenkins for RTC to trigger a build whenever there are incoming changes in repository workspace.

Thanks.

Comment: which version of the plugin were you using? does it work correctly with a current version? watch out, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rational+Team+Concert+Plugin is deprecated, so i assume you tried with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Concert+Plugin

Comment: If you are building from a workspace, you can only have 1 job polling (frequently), because once the changes are picked up -- wsr vs. stream and built, you wont be able to poll for them again as they'd already have been accepted into that workspace...

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use the [compare](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/topic/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/compare.html) command when polling for changes.  Make sure you use the correct [RTC Info Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=3488&uid=swg27012781) for your RTC version.  But, using the SCM command line will be tricky.  Build does component replaces into the build workspace instead of just accepting incoming changes.  The former properly handles discarded change sets and performs better than the latter.

If you use the [Team Concert plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Concert+Plugin) you can specify a build definition.  Make sure the build definition has the "Jazz Source Control" option and check "Create folders for components".

Future Jazz questions will get more attention if posted on the [Jazz Forum](https://jazz.net/forum).

Hope that helps!

Scott